# Query Function with unique Filter 2 column when the criteria match in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Maintenance Schedule sheet for Fleet maintenance in that I need to copy the data to another sheet whenever service status is "Live" and Equipment, Types of service to filter is unique. I need help to find out the formula.

Sample formula I tried whether it is right or wrong:

[Spreadsheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BUDC1euAHQXZ9rME7XEmV8YECrCH5DBmC7pM2lCzln0/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(query('Master Schedule'!A1:O,"Select B,E,F,M,N,O where O='Live'",1),
              Query('Master Schedule'!A1:O,"Select * "&UNIQUE('Master Schedule'!B2:E)&"",1))

=Query(Query('Master Schedule'!A1:O,"Select B,E,F,M,N,O where O='Live'"),
       "Select '"&UNIQUE({'Master Schedule'!B:B, 'Master Schedule'!B:B&'Master Schedule'!E:E, 'Master Schedule'!E:E})&"'",1)

=Arrayformula(VLookup(Filter(Unique('Master Schedule'!B:B &'Master Schedule'!E:E);
              Unique('Master Schedule'!B2:E)<>"");Query('Master Schedule'!A:O; "Select B, E,F,M,N,O ";1); {1\2\3\4\5\6};0))
```

[Master Schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgcbF.jpg)

[Result Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2O5C.jpg)

Comment: Thank you Mr.Mike steelson will share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
=query(arrayformula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(unique((Data!B:B&"~"&Data!E:E&"~"&Data!F:F&"~"&Data!M:M)),
query({arrayformula(Data!B:B&"~"&Data!E:E&"~"&Data!F:F&"~"&Data!M:M),Data!B:B,Data!E:E,Data!F:F,Data!M:O},"select * where Col7='Live'"),
{2,3,4,5,6,7},0))),"select * where Col1 is not null")
```

or with semicolon notation

```
=query(arrayformula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(unique((Data!B:B&"~"&Data!E:E&"~"&Data!F:F&"~"&Data!M:M));
query({arrayformula(Data!B:B&"~"&Data!E:E&"~"&Data!F:F&"~"&Data!M:M)\Data!B:B\Data!E:E\Data!F:F\Data!M:O};"select * where Col7='Live'");
{2\3\4\5\6\7};0)));"select * where Col1 is not null")
```

### explanation

build a unique reference as `unique(Data!B:B&"~"&Data!E:E&"~"&Data!F:F&"~"&Data!M:M)`

build a new matrix with this reference and only 'live' rows as `query({arrayformula(Data!B:B&"~"&Data!E:E&"~"&Data!F:F&"~"&Data!M:M),Data!B:B,Data!E:E,Data!F:F,Data!M:O},"select * where Col7='Live'")`

then apply vlookup

Comment: Can we use Filter function instead of Query function ?

Comment: Not sure I can do that. I'm less confident with Filter and don't know how to omit extra columns (references) at the end. I tried but failed.